# Distance between two closed sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory

In $\mathbb{R}^n$, I read that given a closed set $E$ that is disjoint from a compact set $F$, under distance $d$, we always have $d(E,F) > 0$, i.e. $d$ can be Euclidian distance. I understand the proof which uses the finite covering of $F$ given its compactness.

But I would like to ask what happens if ever the compactness of $F$ is taken out, i.e. we only assume that $F$ is closed. Are there cases whereby $E$ and $F$ are disjoint, both are closed, but $d(E,F) = 0$. Why is compactness of $F$ necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. $A=\{2,3,4,...\}$ and $B=\{2+\frac 1 2, 3+\frac 1 3,4+\frac 1 4...\}$ are disjoint closed sets in $\mathbb R$ with $d(A,B)=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $E$ as the $x$ axis, for $x\ge 1,$ and $F$ as the graph of $y=1/x,$ again for $x\ge 1.$ These are disjoint. Both are closed in the  $xy$ plane but distance is zero.